# React-router: Preventing hash (#) links from re-rendering components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, react-router

In bootstrap hash links are used to toggle collapsible panels:

```
<Link to='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target={dataTarget} aria-expanded='false'>{this.props.text}</Link>
```

When clicking a link like this I would like react router to not re-render the components.

The above link is used in an nav-menu that overflows some page content. When the link is clicked in the menu it causes the page content to refresh. This happens because react router picks up the click on the link and as a result the route for the current page is triggered.

How can I avoid this so the link just toggles the collapsible panel without causing a re-render?

Answer (score 0):

remove `#` from to='#'` and it won't refresh.

Comment: If I do: to='' react router just navigates to the root of the site

Comment: ?what is the rendered html look like